# JS Numeric and Hyphen validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I am using Javascript to validate phone number with hyphen. It is validating only one hyphen but not allowing two hyphens.

I want to validate this format:

> `123-456-7891`

How can I do this with JS?
This is my function

```
 function numericValidation(phoneno) {
     var numbers = /^\d+((;\d+)*|-\d+)?$/;
     if (phoneno.match(numbers)) {
         alert('Your input is valid');
         return true;
     } else {
         alert('Please enter in (123-456-7891) format');
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Personally I find it better to accept input, remove spaces/hyphens and validate/store whatevers left, formatting subsequently for display only.

Comment: `/^\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,4}$/`

Answer (score 2):

```
 function numericValidation(phoneno) {
   var numbers =/^\d+(-\d+)*$/;
   if (phoneno.match(numbers)) {
     alert('Your input is valid');
     return true;
   }
   else {
     alert('Please enter in (123-456-7891) format');
     return false;
   }
 }
```